# What is content-type for retrieving audio file with Multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I have retrieved image using `Multer` with `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');` 

What is the content type to retrieved audio file which is in `mp3` format ?

Comment: its depend on audio file  like this
`res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/basic')`

Comment: `audio/*` replace `*` with format